# Angular use CSS variable in global style.css file

Tags: css, angular, css-variables

How to use CSS variable in global CSS file

Just check style.css file in stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-themeing-y3jwrk?file=src/styles.css

Comment: You have a variable in a typescript class and you want to use that variable in CSS to change the styles? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: CSS variable works inside component but i'm not able to use that in styles.css file

Answer (score 10):

in the global css file, styles.css, I have this code:

```
import ...

:root {
    --main-color: #3f51b5;
}
```

it declares a css variable, "main-color"

then in the child component css file, I can use the variable directly

```
#component-body {
  background: var(--main-color);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In the global style.css file, define custom properties in a `:root` selector.

Global variables in CSS will enable us to define theme variables such that multiple components can use the same.

Here you go:

**app/style.css**

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
  --background-color: #e5e5e5;
  --text-color: #2d2d2d;
}
```

To define a CSS custom property,prefix the property with two '--' like `--text-color:#2d2d2d`.

Now we can reference the variable in other CSS files.To use a custom property, use the `var` keyword to pass in a reference to the custom property.

**app/header/header.component.css**

```
:host {
background-color: var(--primary-color);
color: var(--text-color);
}
```